# Integer field prefix zero not displaying

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):         
    number1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False,error_messages={'invalid':'Enter a valid phone number'})
    number2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False,error_messages={'invalid':'Enter a valid phone number'})
    number3 = forms.IntegerField(required=False,error_messages={'invalid':'Enter a valid phone number'})
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneInfo
        fields = ['name1','number1','name2','number2','name3','number3','emergency','emergency_number']
```

models.py

```
class PhoneInfo(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name1 = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number1 = models.CharField('Number',max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    name2 =  models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number2 = models.CharField('Number', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    name3 = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number3 = models.CharField('Number',max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    emergency = models.CharField('Emergency', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    emergency_number = models.CharField('Emergency Number',max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

The nmber1,number2 and number3 are used to save 11-digit phone number.My problem is if i add 1st digit as '0' after save '0' gets disappeared from form field.I i add that "0" after 1st digit it is saving and displaying.Problem is with this :08854215452  1st zero gets disappear after save.I want to show that also while saving phone number with STD code.

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  158.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  164.             self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  124.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  91.                 lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/root/Projects/ir_uploaded_copy/ir/setting/views.py" in <module>
  22. from setting.forms import *
File "/root/Projects/ir_uploaded_copy/ir/setting/forms.py" in <module>
  151. class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "/root/Projects/ir_uploaded_copy/ir/setting/forms.py" in PhoneForm
  162.     emergency_number = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?(\d{3}-?\d+{7})$', error_messages = {'invalid':'Enter a valid phone number'})
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in __init__
  437.             regex = re.compile(regex)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py" in compile
  190.     return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py" in _compile
  245.         raise error, v # invalid expression

Exception Type: error at /setting/call/
Exception Value: multiple repeat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never save phone numbers as `IntegerFields`. The behaviour you're seeing is normal for integers in any programming language.

```
>> myInt = 00001
>> print myInt
>> 1
```

What should you store it as? Either you a) write your own field, b) choose  `CharField` or choose a `RegexField`

When it comes to phonenumbers I usually prefer a regex field ***if*** you're in a set region of the world, Sweden for example would have the regex below:

```
phone_number = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?(\d{3}-?\d+{7})$', error_messages = {'invalid_phonenumber': _("Not a valid Swedish phone number.")}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this regex of the top of my head, it might not be 100% accurate, sorry! :) try `r'\d+'` please. That regex will grab all digits inside a string ie. it won't work with hyphens and such.

Comment: Excellent,r'\d+' is working fine,except it is taking the combination of integer and character,can you tell me how to avoid that.(not taking pure character)

Comment: Just using `r'\d+'` should be enough not to take anything but digits.

Comment: But it is accepting the combination of digits and character like this "15555534ssd".If the input is like "15555534ssd" it is accepting and saving the values.

Comment: Hai limelights,any idea how to solve this,i goggled and checked with some regix format,still not got the exact one.

Comment: Strange, I must miss something, try `r'^[0-9]+$'` this should capture just, just, just the digits.

Answer (score 2):

NEVER treat phone numbers as integers! Always use CharFields and maybe do a little bit of validation if necessary. Be sure that you do not only allow digits, but also "-", " " etc.

Your ModelForm might look like this:

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneInfo
        fields = ['name1','number1','name2','number2','name3','number3','emergency','emergency_number']

    def clean_number1(self):
        n = self.cleaned_data.get('number1')
        for allowednondigit in '- ./':
            n.replace(allowednondigit, '')
        for char in n:
            if char not in '0123456789':
                raise forms.ValidationError("Please only use digits, spaces, dots, slash and dash characters")
        return n
```

That way you store only digits (if that is what you REALLY want) in your database while still letting your user to write a phone number as he is used to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I would like to mention that the ```n.replace(allowednondigit, '')``` approach -for the part where we want to allow some additional characters- will not work. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941385/integer-field-prefix-zero-not-displaying/28485058#28485058) I have posted my working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever seen phone numbers stored in `models.CharField`s because of this exact reason.

Instead of using `forms.IntegerField` on your form, use `forms.CharField`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Integer will ignore leading zero. You can make that 0 as implicit 
(actually it is implicit) or convert this to text field.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my working solution, based on [mawimawi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941385/integer-field-prefix-zero-not-displaying/17941494#17941494).

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneInfo
        fields = ['name1','number1','name2','number2','name3','number3','emergency','emergency_number']

    def clean_number1(self):
        n = self.cleaned_data.get('number1')
        allowed_characters = '0123456789- ./'
        for char in n:
            if char not in allowed_characters:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Please only use digits, spaces, dots, slash and dash characters")
        return n
```